# Localizable WPF Application - UICulture settings lead to Resource problems

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, localization, currentuiculture

I want to create aa localizable WPF Application. I've followed the instructions in the comments of the AssemblyInfo.cs file:

```
//In order to begin building localizable applications, set 
//<UICulture>CultureYouAreCodingWith</UICulture> in your .csproj file
//inside a <PropertyGroup>.  For example, if you are using US english
//in your source files, set the <UICulture> to en-US.  Then uncomment
//the NeutralResourceLanguage attribute below.  Update the "en-US" in
//the line below to match the UICulture setting in the project file.
```

After I've done this, my application isn't starting any more. I'm using a custom App class:

```
namespace Namespace
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        [STAThread()]
        [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand)]
        public static void Main()
        {
            var app = new App();

            app.InitializeComponent();
            app.Run();
        }


        [DebuggerNonUserCode()]
        public void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.StartupUri = new Uri("MainWindow.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
        }
    }
}
```

```
<ns:App
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:ns="clr-namespace:Namespace">

</ns:App>
```

Everything has worked fine before. I assume there's some kind of mismatch between the configured UICulture settings and that one specified for MainWindow.xaml, but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had a similar effect; in the AssemblyInfo.cs, the `NeutralResourcesLanguage` attribute needed the `UltimateResourceFallbackLocation.Satellite` parameter:

```
// Uncommenting the following line --> OK
[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en-US", UltimateResourceFallbackLocation.Satellite)]
// Uncommenting the following line --> IOException: Cannot locate resource 'app.xaml'.
// [assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en-US", UltimateResourceFallbackLocation.MainAssembly)]
// Uncommenting the following line --> IOException: Cannot locate resource 'app.xaml'.
// [assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en-US")]
```

Comment: Count me in, had esoterical error deploying to one of two similar machines, because one of them had a different OS language. Now things are fine.

Answer (score 0):

Some background info from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/wpf-globalization-and-localization-overview

Best Practices for WPF Localization

- Set the `UltimateResourceFallback` location in AssemblyInfo.* to
  specify the appropriate language for fallback (for example,
  `[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en-US",
  UltimateResourceFallbackLocation.Satellite)]`).
- If you decide to include your source language in the main assembly by
  omitting the `<UICulture>` tag in your project file, set the
  `UltimateResourceFallback` location as the main assembly instead of the
  satellite (for example, `[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en-US",
  UltimateResourceFallbackLocation.MainAssembly)]`)

.